# disable kendo default grouping row selection

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How do I disable selection for the default grouping header? My grid has `selectable: 'multiple'` and grouping is set to false (i don't want to user to group, but i want to specify the grouping myself). This means the grouping header is also selectable. How do i make the grouping header row be not selectable?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply state what the default grouping should be in the `dataSource` property of the Kendo grid:

```
dataSource: {
    ...
    group: {
       field: 'NameOfFieldYouWantToGroup'
    }
}
```

And ensure the `groupable` attribute is set on the top level grid intialisation:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ...
    groupable: false
});
```

Here is a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ocElE/13) of predetermined groupings (with the option to remove the grouping removed)